# sentry do not show events

Tags: python, sentry

```
raven test http://483c3952b67247de91cb039622da7966:93a97682c316413db8092d597b3ef1a5@182.92.11.6:9000/2
Using DSN configuration:
  http://483c3952b67247de91cb039622da7966:93a97682c316413db8092d597b3ef1a5@182.92.11.6:9000/2

Client configuration:
  servers        : ['http://182.92.11.6:9000/api/2/store/']
  project        : 2
  public_key     : 483c3952b67247de91cb039622da7966
  secret_key     : 93a97682c316413db8092d597b3ef1a5

Sending a test message...
success!
Event ID was 'bc73d1e11ee34137b50656bffa1a0e0f'
```

raven test success

but event do not show in sentry.

Answer (score 7):

I just had this same issue and my problem was very simple. I was not running the workers. I added the workers to my supervisord.conf and problem solved.

http://sentry.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart/index.html#starting-the-web-service

> Starting the Workers A large amount of Sentry’s work is typically done
>   via it’s workers. While Sentry will seemingly work without using a
>   queue you will not actually see anything show up in Sentry. Once
>   you’ve configured the queue, you’ll also need to run workers.
>   Generally, this is as simple as running “celery” from the Sentry CLI.
>
> So do not forget to run the workers!
>
> sentry --config=/etc/sentry.conf.py celery worker -B